# Random order for group of rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, random, group-by, sql-order-by

maybe it´s easy but i have no clue how to handle this correctly. I have the following table t1 with this data:

```
-----------------
| id    | gr_id |
-----------------
| 1     | a     |
| 2     | a     |
| 3     | b     |
| 4     | b     |
| 5     | c     |
| 6     | c     |
| 7     | d     |
| 8     | d     |
-----------------
```

I would like to get randomly gr_ids like this:

```
-----------------
| id    | gr_id |
-----------------
| 3     | b     |
| 4     | b     |
| 5     | c     |
| 6     | c     |
| 7     | d     |
| 8     | d     |
| 1     | a     |
| 2     | a     |
-----------------
```

Getting ordered gr_ids ascend and descend is pretty easy, but getting randomly grouped results, is pretty more complicated than i thought it is.

I do not get it, when i use GROUP BY or sth. similar i get for sure only one row each group. How can i randomly order groups, what is the trick here???

Thank you guys for bringing light into darkness ;)

Comment: Join a random arrangement of distinct groups onto your table. And note that group is a silly word for a table/column identifier

Comment: You´re right, but it was just an examle. I changed it. Can you pls explain your comment a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E.g.:

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT DISTINCT gr_id
                     , RAND() rnd 
                  FROM my_table
     ) y
    ON y.gr_id = x.gr_id
 ORDER 
    BY y.rnd
     , x.id;
```

Comment: WOW, perfect. I do not understand it right now, but it works.

Comment: This got me really close to what I needed, but I had to add a group by gr_id clause within the join to prevent the join from creating extra rows in the outer select query.  I think this is what the "distinct" clause was after, but because of the second rand() column it didn't actually capture distinct gr_id values.

Comment: @mkonji You have identified a flaw in this answer. I'll have a think about a proper way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY RAND()` should work for you.