# select random rows from group using mysql

Tags: mysql

Table - productvariant

```
_id productid   productname    optionid  optionprice
1   1             product - 1   101        499
2   2             product - 2   105        499
3   1             product - 1   102        499
4   1             product - 1   103        499
5   2             product - 2   106        499
6   2             product - 2   107        499
7   1             product - 1   104        499
8   2             product - 2   108        499
```

I want to do group by using productid column in above table and expects random rows each time when I execute.

Expected output :

```
_id productid   productname   optionid  optionprice
3    1          product - 1    102         499
6    2          product - 2    107         499
```

OR

```
_id productid   productname    optionid optionprice
2    2           product - 2    105       499
7    1           product - 1    104       499
```

Want to select random rows by product in each execution of the query.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you were looking for a max or min value instead of random, would you know how to solve the problem?

Comment: @royg seeing as the linked question is about mssql, I'm not convinced it's a duplicate (although I accept that this question has been asked before)

Comment: @Strawberry Yes, SELECT MAX(optionprice) FROM (SELECT * FROM productvariant ORDER BY RAND()) temp GROUP BY temp.productid

Comment: @RoyG - Not sure, its duplicate or not, but the link you have suggested above, doesn't have use of group by clause and actually the problem here happens due to group by.

Comment: !! @Rush1312 that's a 'No' then !!

Comment: @Strawberry - why "No", its getting me the output as expected.

Comment: The subquery serves no purpose

Comment: @Strawberry - ok, thanks, would it be fine - SELECT MAX(optionprice) from productvariant group by productid;

Comment: Well, that's half the battle. You'd normally want to find the row associated with that value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL Select One Random record from each Category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245275/mysql-select-one-random-record-from-each-category)

Answer (score 0):

Already answered here: [MYSQL Select One Random record from each Category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245275/mysql-select-one-random-record-from-each-category)

Taking the idea from above link. Try this:

```
SELECT inner_nest.* FROM 
( SELECT * FROM productvariant ORDER BY RAND() ) AS inner_nest 
GROUP BY inner_nest.productid
```

Comment: I'm downvoting this on philosophical grounds, because randomness and indeterminacy aren't quite the same thing. That said, as I'm not able to characterise the difference, I'm withdrawing my downvote.

Comment: I have tried this, but unfortunately Its not working. Get same rows everytime.

Comment: @Rush1312 pls check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38073130/2469308
It is same as your question. Can you provide a SQLfiddle ?

Comment: @Rush1312 Although it's true that this is a 'hack' solution, against the SQL standard, nevertheless, it *should* work - and is much simpler than a 'standard-compliant' solution. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c10a83/1

Comment: @Strawberry - Yes, indeed. I have tried as you show in the example, but its not working for me. Not sure if its mysql workbench version issue. i am using version 6.3 and its not working even though I have copied your statements from  the example. I have tried it in another online editor where its not working - https://paiza.io/projects/VDOOLs3C1C5VrK_nRKZ3-Q?language=mysql

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya - It is not working for me. Is it any issue with sql_mode ? please check this - https://paiza.io/projects/VDOOLs3C1C5VrK_nRKZ3-Q?language=mysql

Comment: Guys, any news ?